# How can I have the HOME directory for one user on an external drive?

Tags: unity, configuration, usb-drive, users

I want to have the HOME directory of one user on an external drive and the HOME directories of all other users in the usual place.

Answer (score 2):

As the user, or as root, you can use "Users & Groups" settings dialog (search for it using the dash) to accomplish this:

```
Users & Groups --> Select the user --> Properties --> Advanced --> Home Directory
```

Note that you must move/copy the data to the external drive manually first, and then use the settings dialog to point it there.

You can also achieve this using usermod on the command line (as root or the user):

```
usermod --home /path/to/external/drive --move-home USERNAME
```

where USERNAME is the name of the user whose folder you want to move. Note that --move-home moves the data of the folder for you, so unlike the method using the settings dialog, you will not have to do this yourself.

Comment: Please, could you give me an example of "/path/to/external/drive"?

Comment: The real problem I'm having is with knowing which path is this!

Comment: @AlbertoSalviaNovella /path/to/external/drive is the mountpoint that your external drive is accessible on. If you mounted the drive manually, then this path is just the mountpoint you specified. You can take a look at the output of lsblk if you don't remember. If the drive was mounted automatically, you may want to mount it manually and permanently (esp. if it is going to contain a home folder). Have a look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive